# What does it mean to 占便宜？

Tags: translation, idioms

What exactly does it mean to 占人家便宜？ Are there other ways of using 占便宜？

My general understanding is that it means to get the better or others, but I'm never sure when or how to use it properly.

Comment: It's been said in the comments below, but the real indication of what is being meant here is more along the lines of: 'to cop a feel' or some sort of molestation towards a woman (most likely).

Answer (score 1):

占便宜 means "to take (unfair) advantage (at other people's expense)", "to profit at others' expense".

Comment: 查字典例如爱词霸怎么样?－＞百度：2. [advantage]∶比喻有优越的条件，做某件事很有好处  2. 谓有优越条件，做某件事可以得心应手。如：小琳个子高，打排球占便宜。3.耍流氓 非礼女士

Comment: `占人家便宜` has a strong indication of the 3rd meaning S.Rhee pointed.

Comment: why ＂but＂ in uppermost comment？
耍流氓  take liberties with women ； act indecently， 
非礼 impolite 女士 woman

Comment: 刑档内幕：第6集 （电视剧） http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTA0NzYxMDky.html?from=y1.2-2.4.6 has example of meaning ＃３，时间标记
３９：３７：讲故事的人：从那以后，
３９：３９：黎志伟用抚养孩子为理由，
３９：４１：隔三岔五地
３９：４３，来向傅红要钱和占她的便宜

Answer (score 1):

`便宜` has 4 meanings:

> (1)便宜
>   bian4yi2
>   [convenient] 便当,合宜
>
> (2)便宜
>   pian2yi
>   [small advantages] 小利益
>   得点儿小便宜
>
> (3)便宜
>   pian2yi
>   [let sb. off lightly] 使某人得到宽恕
>   不能便宜了他
>
> (4)便宜
>   pian2yi
>   [cheap] 花费很少,尤指与现行价格或实际价值相比较时

2nd is related to `占便宜`

`占便宜`
zhan4 pian2yi
(1)[gain extra advantage by unfair means]∶用不正当的方法,得到非分的好处
(2)[advantage]∶比喻有优越的条件.example:他个子高,打篮球占便宜

`占人家便宜`
In my opinion it has 2 meanings:

1. [take some thing/profit dosnot belong to you]因为他给你算错账，所以你是占人家便宜了。
2. [some sort of molestation towards a woman]不要因为姑娘漂亮就占人家便宜。

Sometimes you passively see or touch a women also can called `占人家便宜`. 他只是想扶她一下，没想到却扶到了胸上，占了人家便宜。